# What does the Wheeler-DeWitt equation imply about the Schrödinger equation concerning the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The WDW equation is: $\hat{H}(x)|\psi \rangle=0.$ Schrödinger’s time dependent wave function equation says: $$i\hbar \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} | \Psi(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\Psi(t)\rangle.$$

Does it make any sense at all to equate these two wave functions? If Wheeler-DeWitt is true, does that imply $$i\hbar \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}|\Psi(t)\rangle=0?$$

I doubt this is important, but the question does intrigue me because I am curious about how the wave function works mathematically and I only recently learned about the Wheeler-DeWitt equation.

Ultimately, what would this mean physically?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler–DeWitt_equation): “Although the symbols $\hat H$ and $|\psi \rangle$ may appear familiar, their interpretation in the Wheeler–DeWitt equation is substantially different from non-relativistic quantum mechanics. 
$|\psi \rangle$  is no longer a spatial wave function in the traditional sense of a complex-valued function that is defined on a 3-dimensional space-like surface and normalized to unity. Instead it is a functional of field configurations on all of spacetime. …

Comment: … This wave function contains all of the information about the geometry and matter content of the universe. $\hat H$ is still an operator that acts on the Hilbert space of wave functions, but it is not the same Hilbert space as in the nonrelativistic case, and *the Hamiltonian no longer determines evolution of the system* [emphasis mine], so the Schrödinger equation 
$\hat{H} |\psi\rangle = i \hbar \partial / \partial t |\psi\rangle$ no longer applies. This property is known as timelessness.”

Comment: I am sure that the theorists can make sense of Wheeler-DeWitt for you, but from an experimental standpoint it is very questionable. A wave function is the description of a quantum mechanical ensemble. Where does one get a quantum mechanical ensemble of universes from? And what would the time variable be? There is no notion of one global time in a relativistic universe. In such a universe all physics is necessarily local and observer dependent. And if we get past that, where do we get quanta from? Quanta are irreversible energy exchanges. What does the universe exchange energy with???

Comment: @FlatterMann You are saying experimental physicists do not have a consensus on this equation because it does not necessarily pan out experimentally? Ie, little to no experiments exist which support this?

Comment: @Ghoster Do you mean Wheeler-DeWitt is completely separate from Schrödinger’s equation because it is time dependent? In short, one is time dependent, the other is not?

Comment: @Ghoster this begs the question : is there a time independent Schrödinger equation? Perhaps I need to check Wikipedia… UPDATE: there is a time independent version. Does my original substitution hold in the case of the time independent equation, or is there still an issue because the WDW is about “timelessness”? Perhaps a full answer could explain all of this ?

Comment: *Is there a time independent Schrödinger equation?* Yes.

Comment: I’m not enough of an expert on the WdW equation to feel competent to write an answer.

Comment: @Jexe No offense, but as far as I know we are still defining physics as the description of nature. I more than happy to participate in an experiment that can measure the wave function of the universe as soon as somebody invents a "universe source" that can produce a brand new universe at the click of a button. Barring that I suggest that you think about the equation in terms of "intellectual nonsense" and "It's not even wrong!". That doesn't mean it's completely useless. Theoretical physics often gets to important results by playing with toys for a long time, first.

Comment: *Is there still an issue because the WDW is about “timelessness”?* Yes, I think there is. The TISE is a direct consequence of the TDSE. If one doesn’t apply, neither does the other, as I see it.

Comment: @Ghoster I completely understand. My entire question revolves around trying to equate the wave functions $\psi$ and $\Psi$. It is honestly a fairly deep curiosity for me.

Comment: $\Psi$ is a wave functional, not a wave function.

Comment: @FlatterMann I totally understand what you mean! An old teacher of mine said something nearly identical to what you wrote years ago!

Comment: @Ghoster I think you’ve answered the question. Essentially. I confused functional and functions. Thank you.

Comment: I know personally that there are physicists who take the WdW equation seriously, because I worked for one. (But it wasn’t my area of research.)  I am sure that many don’t. I believe Hawking (whom I didn’t know) did.

Comment: @Ghoster Like I said, it's probably not even wrong. However, what do we get out of it? A quantum theory of an empty universe? How interesting is that?

Comment: @FlatterMann I’m not sure I understand, but these comments have gone on too long. Interested in a short chat?

Comment: @Ghoster Agreed.

Comment: For some reason the system is not offering to move these comments to chat. Can you meet me in the H Bar chat room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wheeler deWitt equation (WDE) describes a quantum system that doesn't evolve with respect to a parameter $t$. In quantum theory real physical systems are described by quantum observables, not by parameters, so the parameter time is unobservable. So the fact that the WDE state $|\Psi\rangle$ doesn't evolve with respect to parameter time highlights a problem that already existed. The WDE state is a state in which a clock system $C$ with a time observable $\hat{T}$ is entangled with the rest of the universe:
$$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_t|t\rangle|\psi(t)\rangle,$$
where the $|t\rangle$ states are eigenstates of the time observable, see

https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.27.2885

https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04773

The relative state of the rest of the universe $|\psi(t)\rangle$ evolves over time according to some relevant equation of motion such as the Schrodinger equation. There is a corresponding treatment for the Heisenberg picture:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02771

This understanding of time has been experimentally tested too

https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4691

https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.00707

Comment: It sounds like a magic trick because the clock system emulates an irreversible process either way, doesn't it? How is this different from an irreversible classical clock? Is the argument that one can make the correlation at the level of the wave function without having to reduce to classical observables and still observe dynamics? By the same argument every other classical observable can also be emulated by a suitable internal quantum system, which is really just a complicated way of saying that "a ruler consists of atoms that are made of quantum fields".  I believe we already knew that.

Comment: In science, people propose theories, work out their consequences and then conduct critical discussion of those consequences, including experimental tests. When we apply quantum physics to clocks we may learn something new about clocks, or about quantum theory and we may make progress toward a replacement for quantum theory by critical discussion and experimental testing of the theory of quantum clocks.

Comment: @alanf Thank you. I am still not yet ready to understand this. However, I've accepted it as the answer.